# Video is not displayed on IPAD

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, video, html5-video

Video is not displayed on ipad. I have tried with `playsinline` and `webkit-playsinline`. But it's still not working. On safari it's only showing poster image but in chrome it is invisible. On the desktop browser, it's working perfectly. Code is attached below.

```html
<div class="video-player ng-scope ng-isolate-scope active" data-video-player="" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <video id="videoitem-30" class="" playsinline webkit-playsinline src="https://media.cfr.org/content/refugee_crisis_interactive/videos/migrant-caravan-1200.mp4" preload="auto" poster="https://media.cfr.org/content/refugee_crisis_interactive/posters/migrant-caravan-1200.jpg" loop=""></video>
<!-- ngIf: item.video.caption -->
  <figcaption ng-if="item.video.caption" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Honduran and Guatemalan migrants walk through Mexico. Many will seek asylum in the United States.</figcaption>
<!-- end ngIf: item.video.caption -->
</div>
```

Comment: For Ipad, you need to explicitly call play() method on button click.  $('#videoitem-30')[0].play() inside document.ready